# How to convert this Python code to SQL query using only a select statement?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, date

I have created a data frame in Python like given below

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'status': ["Applied", "Applied", "NotApplied", "Applied", "NotApplied", "Applied", "Applied"],
    'date1':   ["2022-02-02", "2022-03-10", np.nan, np.nan, "2022-02-25", "2022-01-16", np.nan],
    'date2':["2022-02-02", "2022-03-10", "2022-02-14", "2022-01-05", "2022-02-25", "2022-01-16", "2022-02-16"]})
    df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
    df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

|  | status | date1 | date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Applied | 2022-02-02 00:00:00 | 2022-02-02 00:00:00 |
| 1 | Applied | 2022-03-10 00:00:00 | 2022-03-10 00:00:00 |
| 2 | NotApplied | NaN | 2022-02-14 00:00:00 |
| 3 | Applied | NaN | 2022-01-05 00:00:00 |
| 4 | NotApplied | 2022-02-25 00:00:00 | 2022-02-25 00:00:00 |
| 5 | Applied | 2022-01-16 00:00:00 | 2022-01-16 00:00:00 |
| 6 | Applied | NaN | 2022-02-16 00:00:00 |

And then applied the below code

```
df.loc[ (df['status'] == 'Applied') , 'date1'] = df['date2']
df = df[df['status'] == 'Applied']
```

|  | status | date1 | date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Applied | 2022-02-02 00:00:00 | 2022-02-02 00:00:00 |
| 1 | Applied | 2022-03-10 00:00:00 | 2022-03-10 00:00:00 |
| 3 | Applied | 2022-01-05 00:00:00 | 2022-01-05 00:00:00 |
| 5 | Applied | 2022-01-16 00:00:00 | 2022-01-16 00:00:00 |
| 6 | Applied | 2022-02-16 00:00:00 | 2022-02-16 00:00:00 |

**Question**

How should I write the above 2 lines of code in SQL using only a select statement (I don't want to alter or update the current table in SQL).

Answer (score 1):

```
select status, date2 as 'date1', date2 from table where status = 'Applied'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your table name and run these query on your sql editor

```
SELECT status,date2 as date1,date2 FROM `Your Table Name` WHERE status='Applied'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
"select * from table_name where status = 'Applied'"
```

just replace table_name with your table name